# How to achieve delayed queue with apache kafka?

Tags: priority-queue, apache-kafka

How do I add delayed jobs on kafka? As I understand it doesn't deal with per message but per topic. My jobs have varying schedule in which I would like them to be consumed. Say one will be in the next 4 hours, another would be i Dec. 1, etc.

Does kafka have native support for this or other 3rd party ways to achieve the same?

I'm thinking of using Redis for the delayed queue instead, and push the job to kafka once its schedule has arrived but if possible I'd like to use only one dependency.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no notion of jobs in Kafka. It is just a dumb high performance message queueing service. Depending on your requirements you may consider storing the jobs in a storage that supports indexing by job execution time like some RDBMS. Then in some process periodically extract the jobs with execution times in some small range [last_check_time, current_time+lookahead_interval] and put them into a Kafka topic for eventual processing.

Answer (score 17):

A bit of a delayed answer here.  It's now possible in the latest Kafka version 0.10+ to consume from a delayed stream, using the new timestamp per message.  I'm using this right now in order to implement a continuous aggregating dataset, without resorting to external dependencies.

These records come through, and may have updates/deletes coming through within the next 60 minutes after the first event, so I can't declare one as "final" until I have seen all the updates.

So, to handle this case, I'm consuming the topic with all CREATEs/UPDATEs/DELETEs twice, the first one in realtime (or as fast as possible), the second one delayed by 90 mins to ensure I don't miss anything.  On the realtime consumer, I'm storing locally all the needed updates for the create.  Then on the delayed consumer, when I receive a particular "CREATE", I'll go lookup my local storage for any updates/deletes, update the record so it knows it's final status, and produce it into a **final** topic into Kafka again.

To ensure I don't run out of disk space, I'm also continuously truncating the local storage so it holds at most two hours of updates/deletes.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Something to keep in mind if I visit Kafka again.

Comment: @mjuarez can you put some light on how to implement this?

Comment: @mjuarez Thanks for the detailed answer. But on the consumer side, I think we have to check the creation time before processing the message. Could you please elaborate on the implementation on the consumer side?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Kafka does not have the ability to delay the visibility of messages like some message queues do. Once a message is published, it will be immediately made available to all consumers. The only minor exception to this is when publishing occurs in transaction scope, and the consumer has enabled read-committed isolation mode. Even then, the delay will be minimal.

Kafka leaves all processing semantics to the consumers’ discretion. If you need to delay processing, you may want to use a persistent data store (e.g. an RDBMS or Redis) or another queue on the consumer end. You most certainly don’t want to block record consumption on the producer with a Thread.sleep(), because this will affect your ability to poll records and Kafka will eventually deem your consumer as having failed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use RabbitMQ which supports this by using **Message TTL** & **Dead letter exchange**

For more info visit:

https://m.alphasights.com/exponential-backoff-with-rabbitmq-78386b9bec81

Comment: Pretty sure he was asking about Kafka so it's not particularly helpful to point to completely different tools and architectures for a pointed question about Kafka. Regardless, using Message TTL and Dead Letter exchanges is not the solution when using RabbitMQ: use delayed exchange type instead.

Comment: @RickO'Shea When you don't find any solution to a problem, you always search for work arounds hence something is better than nothing.
It might help other users in some way.

Comment: @navid_gh Please let that person decide. Request you to not to comment just for the sake of commenting & follow community guidelines.